# Error in android studio CMAKE issues for Alize speaker recogntion project

Tags: android-studio, cmake

I am getting this error 
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

I am  trying to compile a project for which android studio said it needed NDK and then CMAKE. It downloaded both and synced the project but I get this error.

This error got rectified but now I have other errors

```
External Native Build Issues
    Build command failed.
    Error while executing process C:\Users\sriranjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize -BC:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\sriranjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\sriranjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\sriranjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/sriranjan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/sriranjan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/sriranjan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/sriranjan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Configuring done
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:96 (add_library):
        src/main/cpp/alize-core/src/alizeString.cpp
      Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
      .hxx .in .txx
    CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: alize-native
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: C:/research/speaker recognition/android-alize-master/alize/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a
    Build command failed.
    Error while executing process C:\Users\sriranjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize -BC:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\sriranjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\sriranjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\sriranjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/sriranjan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/sriranjan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/sriranjan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/sriranjan/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Configuring done
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:96 (add_library):
        src/main/cpp/alize-core/src/alizeString.cpp
      Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
      .hxx .in .txx
    CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: alize-native
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: C:/research/speaker recognition/android-alize-master/alize/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a
C:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize\build.gradle
    Warning:Warning:Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation' and 'androidTestApi'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
    Warning:Warning:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
    Warning:Warning:Configuration 'androidTestApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
    Warning:Warning:Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
    Warning:Warning:Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
```

Further progress...It is mentioned to add the contents of src folder from alize-core and LIA-RAL. alize-core also has an include folder. Should I add those as well. And LIA-RAL has many folders and many src folders in those folders. So I am not sure how to add the contents from these folders to the cpp folder.

When I added the folders directly I got the following errors.

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':alize'. > executing external native build for cmake C:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize\CMakeLists.txt * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I am not sure how to add the contents of all those folders from the main repo folder.

I get this error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:96 (add_library):
    src/main/cpp/alize-core/src/alizeString.cpp
  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: alize-native
```

Latest error is this

```
Error:(2) error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name: 'AlizeSpkRec'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

This is my manifest tag

```
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="AlizeSpkRec"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

So to overcome the manifest error I gave the package name as com.android.AlizeSpkRec but it gets over written to just AlizeSpkRec. And the AndroidManifest.xml file is located in alize/build/intermediate/manifests/aapt/release and in/debug. Looks like every time I am trying to build the project it is getting rewritten. So where is the actual package name stored and how to change it?

Comment: Complete configuration log, please (add it to the question post). Usually, there is another error message describing that CXX compiler isn't found.

Comment: edited the question, the previous error got solved but now I have other errors..

Comment: Error "Tried extensions ..." means that CMake **cannot find source file**, which has been used for `add_executable`/`add_library`. Without the code, it is difficult to say more.

Comment: Here is the code https://github.com/ALIZE-Speaker-Recognition/android-alize

Comment: From the project's README: "You need to get the source for `alize-core` and `LIA_RAL` from their respective repositories, and put the two source folders at this path: `{project_root}/alize/src/main/cpp/`". Make sure that you have performed this step.

Comment: That is not clear.As I downloaded the repos for alize core and LIA RAL and they have couple of folders in them including the source folder. Do I put all those folders into the cpp folder?

Comment: Content of [src/](https://github.com/ALIZE-Speaker-Recognition/alize-core/tree/master/src) folder of `alize-core` should be in `{project_root}/alize/src/main/cpp/` folder.

Comment: I added the folders directly and I got this error Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':alize'.
> executing external native build for cmake C:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize\CMakeLists.txt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s

Comment: There is an src folder and an include folder in alize-core. Should I add the content of both folders? And coming to LIA-RAL there are many folders with many src folders in them. I am not sure how to add all those..If some one can get this android project compiling and in parallel guide me, it would be great.

Comment: On Stack Overflow comments are badly suited for multiline code and error messages. Edit the question post instead.

Comment: Actually, I don't know actual projects "merging" strategy. Assuming that your project is intended to be built, there is should be file `src/main/cpp/alize-core/src/alizeString.cpp`, referred by it. As for merging other folders... you may follow the same "try-and-fix" strategy - try to build the project, see which file is missing, add this file (and other files from the same folder) from the merged project. And so on.

Comment: Tip about post formatting: Select a code or an error message, and use `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button for format it.

Comment: Cmake cannot determine the linker language..how do I fix this? Yes there is a file alizeString.cpp. I manually checked the folders but I do not know how to fix the cmake error..

Comment: Now I checked the cmakelists.txt file and looked at the path to each of the files and added the folders LIA RAL and alize-core. I also added spro. Now the compilation moved forward. But I get this error In file included from C:\research\speaker recognition\android-alize-master\alize\src\main\cpp\AlizeSpkRec_SimpleSpkDetSystem.cpp:4:
../../../../src/main/cpp/LIA_RAL/LIA_SpkDet/SimpleSpkDetSystem/include\SimpleSpkDetSystem.h:92:3: error: unknown type name 'spflag_t'
                spflag_t SPRO_flag;

Comment: I got past most of the errors but I am getting one more. I edited the question and added the latest error.

Comment: I glad you have overcome CMake errors. As for Android-specific problems, I don't know what they mean. Probably, someone else will able to help you. You may update(edit) your question post to contain **only the latest error** (and corresponded description). Do not forget to update the title.

Comment: In the src folder there is an AndroidManifest.xml file and I changed the package name there and it compiled fine...

Comment: When editing the AndroidManifest file make sure you edit the one in your source src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and that you also update the applicationId in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

All the bugs have been solved as mentioned in the comments. The following are the steps to successfully compile the project. Add alize-core and LIA-RAL folders with the same name as cmakelists.txt file into the respective cpp folder. Add spro latest library folder as well.

If you get spflag_t SPRO_flag error change the data type to int. Only uses spro 5.0 latest package to compile.

Mention the package name as com.android.AlizeSpkRec

And then things should work.

Comment: On Stack Overflow **answers** should be **self-contained**, that is contain information for resolve the problem. Only reference to other place is not sufficient. If you, as asker, feel that you cannot formulate a specific problem, or think that it won't be interested to others, then you may simply delete the question.